# Disable Flask @before_request for testing

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest, flask-login

I have a blueprint named `browse`, which has this part of code:

```
@browse.before_request
def before_request():
    if not current_user.is_authenticated or (current_user.is_authenticated and not current_user.confirmed):
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
```

To do unit test I have to disable this authentication. 
I tried adding `LOGIN_DISABLED = True` in config. But it didn't work. Also tried reinit in *setUp()*. Same result.
Is there any way around?